# Lucene Query and Analyzer combination

Tags: lucene, analyzer

I have a quick question. Say, I've got a string `"this string has some text in it"`. I want lucene to be able to find it using following searches:

```
"string has"
"has this"
"text this"
```

Which combination of Analyzer and Query should I use for that? Lucene 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You probably want to use solr instead of lucene, since it will not require you to know things like this
2. The standard analyzer and query parser will work.